# Using jQuery:remove() to delete/remove form elements off a page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, field

I'm trying to remove a form element generated through Ajax calls, but when I submit the form and var_dump the POST request, I can still see the form field key=>value. I need to be able to completely remove the field through jQuery in order to validate correctly.

Comment: You're going to have to post some code for us to help you.

Comment: You can also just set the "disabled" attribute to `true` in order to keep it out of the POST.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the element first before submitting it.

```
$(this.element).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also not set the name attribute, and the field won't get posted